# Picasso not loading images

Tags: android, image, loading, picasso, okhttp

I have been using Picasso for quite some time, but I had to upgrade OkHttp library to 2.0.0 and, consequently, I had to upgrade Picasso to version 2.3.2.

However, now Picasso does not load any image at all, the imageviews are left empty. No error shows up at any time, but when I turned Picasso logging on, the "Hunter" seems to be dispatched and starts executing, but never finishes.

All the images are accessible and rather small (around 200px by 100px).

I'm loading the images through Picasso's "typical" method:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url).error(R.drawable.errorimg).into(imageView);
```

However, the `errorimg` is never shown.

What could I be doing wrong?

EDIT:

Here is the code of one of the places where Picasso is not working (PlaceListAdapter.java - getView function)

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    final PBNPlace ev = values.get(position);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.places_list_item, parent, false);

    TextView titleView = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.place_title);
    ImageView placeImage = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.place_image);

    Picasso picasso = Picasso.with(context);
    picasso.load(ev.imageURL).error(R.drawable.chat).into(placeImage);

    titleView.setText(ev.name);

    return rowView;
}
```

Comment: Paste some relative code if you want to get more useful help from others.

Comment: Well, this one is probably one of the largest images, since it is a banner: http://www.portobynight.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Hard-Club-08.07.2014-Tert%C3%BAlia-de-Folk-Baile-com-Jam-Session.jpg

Comment: Have you debugged and retrieved the url that you are passing to Picasso? Because you can view it in a browser doesn't always mean it will get resolved by Picasso

Comment: Yes, the URL definitely worked in 2.1.1. I can load no image whatsoever now. :(

Comment: What's the URL? I can confirm that it loads with OkHttp. (if you don't want to share it here, I'm jesse at swank dot ca.)

Comment: @JesseWilson, sure! I did paste an example image URL above, but here it is: http://www.portobynight.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Hard-Club-08.07.2014-Tert%C3%BAlia-de-Folk-Baile-com-Jam-Session.jpg

Although, I've now been trying to load random images from google and nothing works.

Answer (score 3):

When you upgraded OKHttp, did you also upgrade the okhttp-urlconnection dependency?

I had this issue and it turned out I was still calling for version 1.6.0 of okhttp-urlconnection in my build.gradle file.  There were no error messages that made it readily apparent to me that I had overlooked this.

Changing that to 2.0.0 solved the problem.

Comment: I'm not using gradle, but I couldn't find the jar for 2.0.0 for okhttp-urlconnection (I still can't). That might be the problem, I thought that 1.6.0 was the latest version!

Comment: Nope, still no good, unfortunately. I just changed 1.6.0 to 2.0.0 RC1 and it still doesn't work. :(

Comment: https://www.versioneye.com/java/com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection/2.0.0 try this one it worked for me finally.

Answer (score 1):

**Picasso does not have an HTTP client inside of it so saying that is "supports HTTPS" means little.**

*When you pass in a url (whether it has a scheme of http:// or https://) we pass that along to the most appropriate HTTP client there is.*

Maybe that's java.net.HttpURLConnection. Maybe it's that sexy bundle of bytecode OkHttp. The bottom line is that whatever the scheme is we just let the HTTP client handle it.

Any problems you are having with http:// vs https:// are in the configuration of the client, not Picasso.

Said By [JakeWharton](https://github.com/JakeWharton)

So for loading images you just need to add below dependencies in your gradle file.

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.+'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.+'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Reference : https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/500

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

this might be the stupidest answer but sorry for that. Sometimes small things are what we forget. Have you checked your permission.